# Add actions to supported drag actions: PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt4

Im new in python and i would like to do this:

```
drag.start(QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress)
```

But this action is not supported by drag action.
It is possible to add new action to : supported Drag actions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess you mean [`QtCore.Qt.DropActions`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qt.html#DropAction-enum) and [`exec_`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qdrag.html#exec) (`start` is outdated). What are you trying to achieve here?